# Cannot connect to MongoDB database inside Docker Container with mongoose in node.js -- Authentication failed although credentials are correct

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, mongoose

Problem with mongo docker image and mongoose as Object Document mapper to connect to specific db after creating container:

(I made sure that DB_NAME is not undefined...)

```
await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {
```

Idk why, but whenever I try to connect to mongodb in docker container (with docker-compose built) I get this error:

```
error: Failed to establish MongoDB connection: MongoServerError: Authentication failed..
```

But when I try to connect with MongoDB Atlas without the db name just the URI, i can easily connect...

My Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  server: 
    build: 
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 3001:3001
    volumes: 
      - ./server/dist:/home/nodeUser/app/dist
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
  mongodb: 
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: auth
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

MY .env file:

```
PORT=3001
MONGO_URI=mongodb://root:toor@mongodb:27017/auth
DB_NAME=auth
```

Weirdly enough is, when I omit the credentials, so no Authentication required to connect, then it works...

I tried to omit the credentials -- login without auth required: worked
I tried to connect using the same connection uri but without the db name: worked
I checked if db_name could be undefined in process.env.DB_NAME: negative

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Because the user that as used was the root user, and it was not linked to a specific database. In this case, you have to add an option `authSource=admin`.(https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.authSource)

```js
await mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGO_URI}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {
    //...
    authSource: "admin"
}
```

Comment: Based on the question it should be rather `authSource: "auth"` or `authSource: $process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`

Comment: I tried the solution...
Adding authSource with ```authSource: $process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE```

It appears still not to work...
Same error as before.

```
    await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://root:toor@mongodb:27017/admin`, {
      authSource: "admin",
    });
```

Comment: Did you import a dump ? Or did you change your docker-compose multiple times ?